# Bind failed: address already in use with SO_REUSEADDR

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I am building the socket part of a project I am working on and I keep getting `bind failed: address already in use`. I tried to use `SO_REUSEADDR` too but it doesn't seem to solve it. How do I fix this?

EDIT: For anyone getting my problem while testing, there's a file that gets generated in your folder named as the socket name. Delete it and you can keep testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SOCKNAME "farm.sck"

typedef struct sockaddr Sockaddr_t;

int bind_check(int* sfd, Sockaddr_t* sa){
    if((bind(*sfd,sa,sizeof(sa)))==-1){
        perror("bind_check");
        return -1;
    }
    else puts("bind done");
    return 0;
    
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   
   int sock_fd;

   struct sockaddr_un sa;     
   strncpy(sa.sun_path, SOCKNAME, strlen(SOCKNAME)+1);
   sa.sun_family= AF_LOCAL;
   sock_fd = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if(sock_fd == -1){
      perror("socket_create");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   int o = 1;
   if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &o, sizeof(int)) < 0){
      perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   if(bind_check(&sock_fd, (Sockaddr_t*)&sa) == -1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

   puts("OK");
   //[...] 
}
```

This is the output:

```
bind_check: Address already in use
```

I have no clue of what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @RemyLebeau doesn't change the output

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was going to close this as a dupe of that. It seems to be directly on point.

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR is normally used to get around the TIME-WAIT state in TCP sockets. There's nothing analogous in Unix domain sockets. You can't have two sockets both binding to the same address.

Comment: @Barmar so how do I fix this? I have to use Unix sockets. I've tried to manually kill a possible dormant copy of the process but either I can't seem to find it or it's not the right approach

Comment: Use `lsof` to find the other process and kill it.

Comment: @Barmar that's what I've done.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it doesn't work. Did you run it as root?

Comment: [unix.se] would be a better place to ask about that problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In C, `(int) { 1 }` is a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) (C99), producing an [lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category). In this context, it is an object with automatic storage duration, and a lifetime equal to the enclosing block. It is [addressable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of).

Comment: For anyone getting my problem while testing, there's a file that gets generated in your folder named as the socket name. Delete it and you can keep testing.